# Edges of image curves on canvas get distorted on android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, paint

As shown in the image, when I create a image out of curvy path(using PorterDuffXfermode) it looks distorted. The black outline is drawn with the same path but the image peaks out of the edges creating distorted look. I have listed my code below (android:hardwareAccelerated="true" has been set as well). **How can I remove the distortion and align image behind the black outline.**

[image]

```
********************* create image ******************************
// translatedFigure is the curvy figure
// sourcePicture is the image drawn as curvy figure

Canvas gfx = new Canvas(image);
gfx.drawPath(translatedFigure, fillStrokePaint);

// use new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

gfx.drawBitmap(sourcePicture, 100, 100, porterDuffPaint);

gfx.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0,embossPaint); // emboss

gfx.drawPath(translatedFigure, outlinePen); // draw black outline

****************************Draw image on Canvas****************************
    canvasPaint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bigImageSizeOfScreen, mPosX, mPosY, canvasPaint);
    canvas.restore(); 
********************************************************


public void createPaint() {
        // for outline
        outlinePen = new Paint(Color.BLACK);
        outlinePen.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        outlinePen.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        outlinePen.setAntiAlias(true);
        outlinePen.setDither(true);
        outlinePen.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        outlinePen.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        outlinePen.setStrokeWidth(1);


        fillStrokePaint = new Paint(Color.WHITE);
        fillStrokePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        fillStrokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        fillStrokePaint.setDither(true);
        fillStrokePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        fillStrokePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        fillStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        porterDuffPaint = new Paint();
        porterDuffPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));


        embossPaint = new Paint(Color.RED);
        embossPaint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
                | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        embossPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        embossPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        embossPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        EmbossMaskFilter mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(
                new float[]{1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        embossPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're stretching the bitmap to fit a view. For example; Your bitmap file is 50px x 50 px, and your view is 100px x 100px. What are the dimensions of your bitmap and view? Also, how are you settings your new bitmap to a view?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I do use scaling but the problem is there even with scaling factor is 1. I have added the code I use to draw this image on the canvas. The images generated are draw on a big image of the size of screen and then drawn on canvas. I have used  canvasPaint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); for drawing. The problem is there even when ScaleFactor = 1.

Comment: What is the size of the bitmap in pixel dimensions? Also what is your screen size in px?

Comment: The small picture is 202x236 and the big picture which this small one is drawn is 480x725. Then the big one is drawn on Canvas. thanks

Comment: That's your problem. Your drawing a bitmap that too small so it's getting stretched. Every pixel of your original bitmap is drawn on multiple pixels of the screen. To solve your issue, use a larger starting bitmap.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand. Large bitmap which is drawn on the canvas is the same size of the View/canvas.  Multiple small images are drawn on the big bitmap without any scaling. Issue is with the small bitmap generation I think.  In particular, why does the edges of the image shape  poke out of the boundary or outline. That should not be related to scaling. If the generation is correct, then scaling should distort the boundary.